# what is the reason for Window.location.href not working sometimes?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp

jsp page for submit button onclick function in javascript. when i click button first time not redirected to CallService.jsp. I click the button two to three times after that only that page will be redirected.

Pls give me the solution or reason

My Code

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">

function sample()
{

    var uname = document.getElementById("uname").value;
    //var pwd = document.getElementById("pwd").value;

    window.location.href("CallService.jsp?username="+uname);
}


</script>


<body>

<h3>User Login</h3> <br>

<form name="userlogin" method="post">

User Name : <input type="text" name="uname" id="uname"> <br>

Password : <input type="text" name="pwd" id="pwd"> <br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="sample(this);" > 
<input type="reset" value="Cancel"> 

<div id="name"></div>
<div id="email"></div>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**CallService.jsp**

```
<%


  String uname = request.getParameter("username");
  //String pwd = request.getParameter("password");


  out.println(uname);

%>
```

Comment: You are submitting form and redirecting to another form same time. It's not right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button type is

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="sample(this);" >
```

replace it with:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="sample(this);" >
```

**or**

Call your function when submitting form like this:

```
<form method="post" name="fromname" onsubmit="yourfunction()">
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
window.location.href = "CallService.jsp?username="+uname;
```

You are submitting form and redirecting to another form same time. It's not right

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="sample(this);" >
```

You cannot submit and redirect this.

In your servlet / jsp where the form is submitted, redirect the page.

Answer (score 0):

please try:

```
function sample()
{

    var uname = document.getElementById("uname").value;
    //var pwd = document.getElementById("pwd").value;

    window.location.href("CallService.jsp?username="+uname);
    //FUNCTION MUST RETURN FALSE!!
    return false;
}

<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return sample(this);" >
```

this way js function will need to be evaluted before making postback

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try redirecting from you java class, like this

> actionResponse.sendRedirect("CallService.jsp");

Comment: no my requirement is login authentication so i have to call that page using js or ajax only tats y..any way thanks ur reply

Answer (score 0):

Since you are fetching the data using javascript here :

```
var uname = document.getElementById("uname").value;
```

theres no need to use a 'submit' button. Try to change

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="sample(this);" >
```

into

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="sample(this);" >
```